# Unclickable href for html

Tags: html, css

Why is that when i hover my mouse pointer to the a link the hand wont show up

the hand is the one that click the link for `<a href=""></a>` it show up when you hover on the list but mine wont.

the first line of the list the hand show up for the whole area but the other list just the half of the area.

Here is my fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/TBEnf/5/

[image]

Comment: I think you are looking for the `cursor: hand;` CSS code

Comment: Cursor: hand ? cursor: pointer my friend....

Comment: `cursor:hand` appears to only work in IE8-. Of course, `cursor:pointer` doesn't work in IE5.5. Go figure. http://quirksmode.org/css/user-interface/cursor.html Regardless, it doesn't have much to do with this question.

Comment: Exactly. And we are in 2013

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Working fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TBEnf/7/

`.UploadPicture ul li a` should have `display:block;`

Comment: You are welcome. You can select the answer as the Answer and close your question as Answered.